# Issue with SQL inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Ok so I have two mysql tables, the first one is "`tbl_forum`":

```
|MSG_ID|MSG_QUERYID|MSG_ISPARENT| MSG_PARENTID
 1     | 59        | 1          | 1
 2     | 59        | 0          | 1
```

The second one is "`tbl_frs`":

```
|FRS_ID|FRS_QUERYID|FRS_PARENTID | FRS_CONTENT
 1     | 59        | 1           | xxxx
 2     | 59        | 1           | yyyy
```

I want a query which would yield all rows of both `tbl_forum` and `tbl_frs` (join) where `msg_queryid = 59` and `msg_isparent = 1`. So in the example above I would like to get a single row which would look like this:

```
|MSG_ID|MSG_QUERYID|MSG_ISPARENT| MSG_PARENTID | FRS_ID|FRS_QUERYID|FRS_PARENTID | FRS_CONTENT
|1     |59         | 1          | 1            | 1     | 59        | 1           | xxxx
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * from tbl_frs 
JOIN tbl_forum 
  ON msg_queryid=frs_queryid 
WHERE msg_isparent=1
```

but it yielded two rows... (both msg_id 1 and 2...). How can I fix this?

edit

and the winner is:

```
 SELECT /column names.../ FROM tbl_frs JOIN tbl_forum ON tbl_frs.FRS_PARENTID=tbl_forum.MSG_ID WHERE tbl_frs.FRS_QUERYID=59 AND tbl_forum.MSG_ISPARENT=1
```

Comment: Look at your 2 row result set and understand why you are getting it. Both records in your first table will join to both records in the 2nd table and give you 4 records. Then you filter based on the is parent=1. Since that row in the first table can join to both rows in the 2nd table, you will get 2 rows. If you want the MSG_ID of 2 from the first table to drop off, then add a msg_id = 1 to either the join or the where clause.

Comment: Tip: NEVER use evil `SELECT *`. Instead, ALWAYS, name and qualify the columns you actually want returned, e.g. `SELECT x.msg_id, y.frs_id FROM...`

Comment: A SQL query must specify the exact list of columns being returned.  What happens if there are three matches in the first table?  Or none?  If you need column flexibility, you need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to select **ALL** from your two tables where `msg_queryid=frs_queryid AND msg_isparent=1`, right?
Btw, using `*` is not a good practise, you should name your field !

Try this maybe:

```
SELECT 
    FRS.FRS_ID, FRS.FRS_QUERYID, FRS.FRS_PARENTID, FRS.FRS_CONTENT
    F.MSG_ID, F.MSG_QUERYID, F.MSG_ISPARENT, F.MSG_PARENTID
FROM tbl_frs as FRS
INNER JOIN tbl_forum as F ON F.MSG_QUERYID=FRS.FRS_QUERYID AND F.MSG_ISPARENT=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the condition with `FRS_ID=1  AND MSG_ISPARENT =1` then you will get your expect.

You can try this.

```
 SELECT 
    T1.MSG_ID,
    T1.MSG_QUERYID,
    T1.MSG_ISPARENT,
    T1.MSG_PARENTID,
    T2.FRS_ID,
    T2.FRS_QUERYID,
    T2.FRS_PARENTID,
    T2.FRS_CONTENT
FROM tbl_frs AS T2 
JOIN tbl_forum AS T1 ON T1.msg_queryid=T2.frs_queryid 
WHERE T2.FRS_ID=1  AND T1.MSG_ISPARENT =1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b6d0/6)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:

```
SELECT * from tbl_forum JOIN tbl_frs ON msg_queryid = frs_queryid WHERE msg_isparent = 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The query you have mentioned in your question has provided the correct answer to your problem.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_frs JOIN tbl_forum ON msg_queryid = frs_queryid WHERE msg_isparent = 1
```

In the above query, you have told MySQL to fetch all rows where `MSG_ISPARENT` equals to `1`. So SQL takes the value from the column `MSG_QUERYID` (which is `59`) and then it matches the value with `tbl_frs.FRS_QUERYID`.

Now there are two rows in `FRS_QUERYID` with value `59`. So MySQL will return two rows.

> **If you add the condition `FRS_ID = 1` it won't meet your requirement. Be careful!!!**

Because it won't return ***"all rows of both `tbl_forum` and `tbl_frs` (join) where `msg_queryid = 59` and `msg_isparent = 1`"***.

The above query gives you the correct results. Don't change it unless you completely understand what's going on.